# Intercept mouse pointer change on browser's Developer tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any possibility for intercepting the mouse cursor using breakpoints or something like that when it changes? using actual browser's developer tools?

For example, when I hover a div that holds a style="cursor:pointer;" it stop in the developer tools warning me that the mouse pointer has changed and when I hover out it fires again warning me that the mouse pointer changed again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [this article](http://elijahmanor.com/7-chrome-tips-developers-designers-may-not-know/) I've found the solution at Item 3.

Following steps:

1. Go to the specific HTML node at the Elements' Tab;
2. Right click on the Element
3. ContextMenu > Break On > Attributes modifications
4. Define a value for the attribute that will be changed
5. Fires the change

After that, I could notice where this change was being made in the code using the CallStack portion on the Sources' Tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an event to all elements on page and check the cursor style:

```
var oldCursorStyle = 'auto';
var myChangeFunction = function(cursorStyle) {
    console.info('It has changed to: ' + cursorStyle);
};
$('*').mouseenter(function(){
    var currentCursorStyle = $(this).css('cursor');
    if (oldCursorStyle != currentCursorStyle) {
       myChangeFunction(currentCursorStyle);
    }
    oldCursorStyle = currentCursorStyle;
});
```

This only works if all elements that you want to map has "cursor" style propertie in it.